# Is there some kind of local file for my server that I can access from my PC?

Tags: linux, debian, webserver, file-server

I am pretty new to making / using a web server. I've been using Winscp to transfer files back and forth, but for certain applications it would just be a lot simpler if I just had a "file" I could reference for the app to my web server without having to download back and forth. Is there such a file created with Winscp, or is there any other way that I could do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to edit a remote file that is in your web server? Your question isn't very clear. Could you please edit it?

Comment: Also, please edit your question and indicate *where* this webserver is. It is provided by your ISP? By a third party (if yes, which one? access may depend on that)? On a local server in your LAN? If your question gets closed, it can be reopened after you edit.

Comment: Also asked on Unix.SX and answered https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464022/does-winscp-have-a-local-file-on-my-pc-i-can-reference-from-my-web-server although it actually fits better here. It is discourteous to trick people into wasting time and effort answering questions that are already answered.

Comment: sorry, I'm still pretty new to asking questions on here, I asked first there and then came to the realization that this place is better to ask, so I did here, but the first ended up being answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking, if you can make your web server access a file on your local machine, than no (well everything is possible, but this would not be a good solution for many reasons).

---

Note that WinSCP has a function called, [Keep remote directory up to date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_keepuptodate).

With the function running, whenever you make a change to your local file(s) (using any tool you want, like your favorite code editor/IDE), WinSCP will automatically upload the changed file(s) to the (web) server.

[image]

Comment: Gotchya! I do have that option checked and does come in handy, but I was thinking more of being able to use a file on my webserver on my local machine without having to download the whole file. I guess as an example for a use would be that I have some games on my server and being able to play them with the program on my local machine without having to completely download them onto the local machine.

Comment: You cannot use a file without downloading it. It makes no sense. How would the program/game know what's inside the file?

Comment: I guess my thought process is that I'm viewing part of the server basically as an "external storage" of sorts, so if I have files on this external storage, I wouldn't have to download the file locally, if that makes sense.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "download". You have to get the data to the local machine work with them. What's what I mean by "download". You do not have to (at least not permanently) store the data (to a physical file). If that's what you mean. For that you can use some drive-mapping tool.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want to permanently download a file from my server to my hard drive on my local machine, I was not aware of drive-mapping tools, so I will look into that.